# Grafana: Integrating groups with LDAP

Tags: grafana

I need some help integrating Grafana and LDAP. Say I have a group in LDAP that needs to be mapped to Grafana organization, 'MyGroup'.
Does the below ldap.conf have the right configuration so that if user 'Rag Cho' is member of MyGroup, the user will become admin of MyGroup org in Grafana? I have tried the below config and the user is visible in Grafana but the user does not appear to be part of 'MyGroup' org in Grafana.

```
ldap entry:
dn: cn=MyGroup,ou=root
cn: MyGroup
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: cn=Rag Cho,ou=root
```

Part of Grafana ldap.conf:

```
...
search_base_dns = ["ou=root"]
group_search_filter = "(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=%s))"
group_search_base_dns = ["ou=root"]

[servers.attributes]
name = "givenName"
surname = "sn"
username = "uid"
member_of = "cn" # is cn value correct or should it be member?
email =  "mail"

[[servers.group_mappings]]
group_dn = "cn=MyGroup,ou=root"
org_role = "Admin"
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Enable `verbose_logging = true` in ldap.toml. look at the output in the log file of grafana when you connect. you should see a dump of the LDAP response.

```
Ldap User found" logger=ldap info="(*login.LdapUserInfo)(0xc42010a2a0)({\n DN: (string) (len=91) \"CN=Username,OU=User,OU=your ou,OU=Accounts,DC=your company,DC=corp\", ... MemberOf: ([]string) (len=28 cap=32) {\n  (string) (len=84) \"CN=your GroupName"
```

I found that Grafana is being **case-sensitive** on the group name response. The LDAP in my clients cooperation is returning upper case `CN=`

I have to match this exactly in (I guess its a bug, cost me some time to figure out).

Another thing to validate are the group mappings:
`[[servers.group_mappings]]
group_dn = "CN=your GroupName,[... what ever in between],DC=corp"
org_role = "Viewer"`

Also if you have group_filter enabled, which may break your LDAP group response (at least it did in my setup). I have (|memberOf=CN=your Groupname,OU=[...],DC=corp) appended to my `search_filter=`

Comment: For me case sensitive was required.

Answer (score 0):

The member_of attribute must be set to `memberOf`. Everything else looks valid.
Regarding your request

> if user 'Rag Cho' is member of MyGroup, the user will become admin of MyGroup org in Grafana

you have to set `org_id` to the integer of MyGroup in Grafana to map Users of MyGroup (LDAP) to the admin role of MyGroup (Grafana)

```
[[servers.group_mappings]]
group_dn = "cn=MyGroup,ou=root"
org_role = "Admin"
org_id   = 23
```

The [Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/ldap/#group-mappings) is quite good. Maybe you should have a look at the examples there.